# Why does navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() does not capture screen on safari 12.1?

Tags: html, safari, twilio

I am developing an app that captures screen.

I am using twilio video JS sdk for this.

In firefox, I get user media like this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video:{
        mediaSource: 'screen'
    }
})
.then( (stream)=>{
   console.log( stream.getVideoTracks() )
});
```

And this captures screen but in Safari Browser 12.1 when I run above code instead of capturing screen it captures media from camera. I need to capture screen though. How can I do that?